# Access to UserManager in Asp.Net Core 2.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I would like to get a reference to UserManager of Identity, because I would like to create a test user to seed the data.

I get a context:

```
var context = new MyContext(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<ApiContext>>())
```

But now I need a reference to UserManager because I need to use it to create a user in my static SeedData class.

I use an Asp.Net Core 2.0.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you can use thru constructor injection.

Add Identity to Startup.cs

```
public class UsersRepository
{
    public UsersRepository(UserManager<Users> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

  public void Foo(){

    _userManager.DoSomething();

   }
}
```

It works for me just fine.

Comment: The manager may need to be accessed externally. Is it possible to obtain the UserManager using a service provider?